# how to change each nested list in a different index?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the list:

```
    lst = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]] # 3n sublists
```

And I want it to be:

```
    [[2,1,1], [1,2,1], [1,1,2], [2,2,3], [1,3,3], [1,2,4]]
```

The idea is to add 1 to each sublist like this:

each time I change another sublist by the order 0,1,2:

lst[i][0 or 1 or 2] += 1   according the order of the sublists. e.g.: the 1st sublist will be lst[0]**[0]** += 1

the 4th sublist will be: lst[3]**[0]** += 1

the big list has `3n` sublists of length `3`

I tried

```
    lst = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]            
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in (0,1,2):
            lst[i][j] += 1
```

and it returns

```
    [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

indtead of

```
    [[2,1,1], [1,2,1], [1,1,2]]
```

Because I iterated over each sublist, over each element in it. How do I continue to the second sublist right after I changed the object I want?

Comment: You have one loop too many. You want `lst[j][j] += 1`…

Comment: But the list has more than 3 sublists- i wrote 3n

Comment: Something like `lst[i][i % 3] += 1` then.

Comment: I think this is the best idea

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `enumerate`.

**Ex:**

```
lst = [[1,1,2], [1,2,1], [1,1,1]]

for idx, v in enumerate(lst):
    v[idx] += 1
print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 1, 2], [1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: my list is a big list containing 3n sublists. not only 3

Comment: Can you post a sample data and its expected output?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is using `zip`:

```
lst = [[1,1,2], [1,2,1], [1,1,1]]            
for i,j in zip(range(len(lst)), (0,1,2)):
     lst[i][j] += 1
lst
#[[2, 1, 2], [1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple `for` loop, no need to use `zip` or `enumerate`

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i][i] += 1

print(lst) # [[2, 1, 2], [1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to change value at different index in each sub list:
So you will require to maintain current index in sub list at which value needs to be changed. As the sublist size is 3. We will calculate current index in sub list using mod operation. As shown in below code snippet:

```
lst = [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
j = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i][j] += 1
    j = (j + 1) % 3
print(lst)
```

> Output: [[2, 1, 2], [1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 2]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
lst = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
new_lst = [[k+1 if j == i%3 else k for j, k in enumerate(a)] for i, a in enumerate(lst)]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```